# Is it possible to use Query Selector from custom child component?

Tags: lightning, lwc-dom

I have such case.
In ParentComponent I need to pick input field. I am using this.template.QuerySelector('inputChildClass') but it keeps returning nothing. Is it even possible to querySelector child component inside Parent?  Child component has input field. I wanted to do that to check validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot access the internal parts of a child component from a parent component. This is explained in the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom) documentation. Your child must expose an @api property for the parent object to read.

Comment: is it possible to use such approach?
    get inputElement() {
        return this.template.querySelector('input');
    }

@api pathname(){
        this.inputElement.pathname();
    }
 ?

Comment: @Daniel Why are you trying to access the child's internal component? What is your overall objective? Please read about the [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: What I am trying to do is to validate input fields on button click. I have 4 input fields overall. 3 inputs are placed in Parent component and 1 input is coming from custom child component. I used reportValidity() on the 3 inputs which are lighting inputs. On the 4th coming from Parent it simply does not work and I am looking for workaround here.

Comment: @Daniel Just write your own method that the parent can call: `@api reportValidity() { return this.template.querySelector('input').reportValidity() }` (or whatever you'd like to do). This is the recommended way to report errors.